# R, system, mysql

Tags: mysql, r, system

I am trying to use R system to execute a mysql script

```
system("mysql -u userID -ppassword -h host -P port < C:\\Users\\USERID\\PATH\\mysql.sql")
```

but it returns

Warning message:
running command had status 1

I wonder the problem is causing by double \ \ but under CMD it needs \

I don't know how to do it in R

If I try

```
system("mysql -u userID -ppassword -h host -P port dbname")
```

it works,

I also try this in CMD,

```
mysql -u userID -ppassword -h host -P port < C:\Users\USERID\PATH\mysql.sql
```

and it works

Comment: Is that a typo of mixed single and double backslashes in your successful CMD run? And are userid and password hardcoded in `system` call?

Comment: for my CMD run it is always single \ userid and password are always given during the call

Comment: Add the arguments, `intern=TRUE` for more verbose error message. Also, play around with `wait=FALSE` and even `invisible=FALSE`.

Comment: maybe try `Sys.which("mysql.exe")`?